# Can I safely supply 3.3 V from ESP32 GPIO output pins to TXS0108E VccA?

Tags: voltage, current, esp32

I'm trying to output 5 V/5 mA from an ESP32 DevKit v1. For this purpose I'm planing to use a [TXS0108E](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/txs0108e).
The VccB is connected to the USB power supply's 5 V, and for the VccA I'm planning to use one of the GPIO pins of the ESP32 DevKit.

I'm unable to find in the datasheet of the TXS0108E the minimum current requirements of VccA. Is it safe to just directly connect some of the GPIO pins as an output to the VccA, or I need to use a voltage regulator from 5 V to 3.3 V?

I have used the 3.3 V pin of the ESP32 DevKit, and it worked for a while, but my USB power supply blew up. Then I found out that this 3.3 V pin is only an input (even that it supplied to me the 3.3 V).

I'm thinking to connect some resistor in series to limit the current, something like 330 Ω. That would make the maximum current VccA = ~3.3 V/~330 Ω = ~10 mA. Then when I output 3.3 V to TXS0108E input A1, I will get my 5 V at output B1 (limiting there with ~1000 Ω resistor to get ~5 mA of output). Am I thinking it correctly?

I will switch a NOT gate with it and the 5 mA (from the VccB side) will give me the fast needed transition times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can safely use 3.3V GPIO as supply voltage for TXS0108E. ESP32 GPIO pins are rated for 20 or 40 mA, depending on which pin you use, so under normal level shifting use, it should be enough for TXS0108E as it consumes most current during signal transitions and not much DC current.

But the TXS0108E is a wrong component for this and it likely does not work in a meaningful way.

It is meant to translate logic levels bidirectionally between IO pins, it is not meant to switch a DC load.

And the ESP32 DevKit 3.3V pin is not an input only, it is the same as 3.3V MCU supply, which is the correct pin for powering external components that are connected to MCU IO.

Comment: I disagree. I wrote a clarification in my question for the reason I use/need that. I'm not planing to buy other hardware if the one I already have can do the job. This does not answer to my question, even so, thank you for the note.

Comment: I have updated my answer now. You can safely use GPIO pin for the level shifter supply, just don't expect the level shifter to work in your application. It has rise time accelerators that are able to drive a pulse of current to drive CMOS inputs quickly. It is not able to drive continuous current to DC loads. Also the 3.3V pin is same as MCU supply so according to schematics you can draw current out of the 3.3V supply pin so it is not input only.

Comment: Can you please explain why I cannot output a continuous current of 5 mA from the level shifter? The specification states absolute maximum of 50 mA, and then 5 mA shall be absolutely safe. Or not? The topic is not "what the level shifter is designed for", but "what is capable of".

Comment: @verbessern Except for the edge accelerators, the TXS is a passive switch that allows only low voltages to pass; high voltages are generated by the pull-up resistors. The guaranteed drive strength of a high output is 20 µA.

Comment: @CL I'm unable to find that 20 µA into the datasheet. There are test conditions of 20 µA, but nowhere it is stated that it is the maximum guarantied. I thought that by supplying 5 V/10 mA to VccB, I can use this 10mA at my output B side. I'm really lost. Can you give me please some pointers, that I can read about?

Comment: @verbessern The test condition indeed is the guaranteed limit; it's the largest output current for which a VOH is specified. The high output voltage is generated only by the 4 kΩ pull-up resistor; 10 mA will drop the voltage by 4 V. See the [TXS application report](https://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/scea044).

Comment: @CL I have read that top to bottom and have not seen this 4 V drop (I don't understand it all, unfortunately, I'm very sorry). What I see is that for the high output voltage the smart pull-up resistor of 4 kΩ will limit the output to 5 V / 4000 Ω = 1.25 mA.

Comment: @verbessern 50mA is the maximum it can withstand without damage if you accidentally push that much into it. It can't output 50mA. It is rated to sink less than 1mA, and can output 20uA if you allow the 5V supply to drop to about 3.3V. But now you say it drives inverter input, so it does not need 1mA, and thus the TXS can drive it. It should drive CMOS inputs just fine. But not any DC loads like resistors or TTL inputs.

Comment: @verbessern Sorry, 10 mA × 4 kΩ would be 40 V.

Comment: I got it almost all now, but..the thing I don't understand is, why I will drive this level shifter from 3.3 V to 5 V, when for an input >= VccA - 0.2 V (at 3.3 V side) the 5 V side (output) I will get 3.3V for 20 uA of current (from VccB * 0.67). I could just drive the output directly in this case.

Comment: Maybe you could drive the next device directly. You don't say what it is but if it supports TTL levels then no level conversion is needed.

Comment: I wanted to make it easy for several 5 V and 3.3V IC's to work together, but I guess that I have to review the situation and possibly redesign. I'm just impressed that this level shifter shifts to ... the same level. I'm wondering is that a mistake in the datasheet, because for the 102 this VccB * 0.67 is the minimum guarantied, and in the datasheet of 108 it is the typical. If its the minimum then its at least TTL level as you noted. Still...0.7 of VccB would be more close to TTL.

Comment: It level shifts when used properly, not drawing DC current. For CMOS input it draws almost no current. It will be guaranteed that at 20uA it will be more than 0.67*VccB and extremely close to VccB.

Comment: I understand it all now, thank you.